# Changing image on click in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I was building a seating layout using XSLT and came up across an issue of changing the image when the seat is clicked.

What I wanted to do is, when I click any of the seats, the image should change to "selected" seat, another image.

I am wondering if this is possible to do with XSLT. I am using these in a PHP page.

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="regularSeatLayout.css"/>
        <body>
            <div class="seats">
                <h2>
                    <center>Select Your Seats</center>
                </h2>
                <span>
                    <center>Screen Here</center>
                </span>
                <xsl:for-each select="hall/row">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row-id">
                            <xsl:value-of select='@id' />
                        </div>
                        <xsl:for-each select='seat'>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test=". = 'Double'">
                                    <img src="double.png" alt="Double Seat" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <img src="regular.png" alt="Regular Seat" />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <div class="row-id">
                            <xsl:value-of select='@id' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="regularSeatLayout.xsl"?>
<hall>
<row id='A'>
    <seat id='1'/>
    <seat id='2'/>
    <seat id='3'/>
    <seat id='4'/>
    <seat id='5'/>
    <seat id='6'/>
</row>

<row id='B'>
    <seat id='1'/>
    <seat id='2'/>
    <seat id='3'/>
    <seat id='4'/>
    <seat id='5'/>
    <seat id='6'/>
</row>

<row id='C'>
    <seat id='1'/>
    <seat id='2'/>
    <seat id='3'/>
    <seat id='4'/>
    <seat id='5'/>
    <seat id='6'>Double</seat>
</row>
</hall>
```

**Current Output**
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With classic XSLT 1.0, your stylesheet just generates an HTML page, and after that, events such as clicking a button have to be handled by the Javascript in the HTML page. The Javascript can invoke another XSLT transformation to update the HTML page if you want, or it can update it directly.

There's an alternative, which is to use XSLT 3.0 in the shape of the Saxon-JS product. With this, you can write template rules within the stylesheet that are triggered on user events such as mouse clicks, and the stylesheet can then update the HTML page directly without calling out to Javascript. Details at http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml Disclaimer: Saxon-JS is my company's product.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Kay suggested, I used Javascript to update the image on click.

Here are the snippets:

**Javascript**

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        <![CDATA[         
         function changeImage(element, type) {
            if(type == 'double'){
               element.src = element.bln ? "../img/doubleSeat.svg" : "../img/selectedSeat.svg";             
            }
            else if(type == 'regular'){
               element.src = element.bln ? "../img/regularSeat.svg" : "../img/selectedSeat.svg";
           }

            element.bln = !element.bln;  /* assigns opposite boolean value always */
           }         
        ]]>
        </script>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:for-each select='seat'>
<xsl:variable name="seatID" select="@id"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=". = 'Double'">
        <img src='../img/doubleSeat.svg' name='{$rowID}{$seatID}' onclick="changeImage(this, 'double')" />
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
        <img src='../img/regularSeat.svg' name='{$rowID}{$seatID}' onclick="changeImage(this, 'regular')" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```